# Is there some way to get count of How many connections are used from Pool

Tags: .net, connection-pooling

I want to write such thing,

in my unit test I want to know is there connection leak?
So I want to get count of used from Pool conections before, and get after it should be equal, tests are STA, so it must work

so, question is in title of this

Comment: There's a performance counter for it, you can see it with Perfmon.exe.  Category = ".NET CLR Data", Counter = "SqlClient: Current # pooled connections".  The Instance should be your test runner.  Use WMI or PerformanceCounter to read it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but give it a try.

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS Number_Of_Connections FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions 
WHERE program_name='your connection str application name'`

or count based on the database name

`SELECT DB_NAME(dbid) as 'DbNAme', COUNT(dbid) as 'Connections' from master.dbo.sysprocesses with (nolock) WHERE dbid > 0 GROUP BY dbid`

Comment: In this case the OP is referring to a specific .NET CLR Counter.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like the following sample console app:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"SAMPLE_CONNECTIONSTRING"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SAMPLE_TABLE";
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                //Used to show that values update based on connections in use.
                //dr.Dispose();
                //cmd.Dispose();
                //conn.Dispose();

                //create our WMI searcher
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_PerfRawData_NETDataProviderforSqlServer_NETDataProviderforSqlServer");
                //now loop through all the item found with the query
                foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Class Win32_PerfRawData_NETDataProviderforSqlServer_NETDataProviderforSqlServer");
                        Console.WriteLine(obj.Properties["Name"].Value);

                        Console.WriteLine("Connection Pools " + obj.Properties["NumberOfActiveConnectionPools"].Value);
                        Console.WriteLine("Pooled Connections " + obj.Properties["NumberOfPooledConnections"].Value);
                        Console.WriteLine("Active Connections " + obj.Properties["NumberOfActiveConnections"].Value);
                        Console.WriteLine("Free Connections " + obj.Properties["NumberOfFreeConnections"].Value);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //throw new Exception("Failed to enumerate a WMI command.", ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

[VB Code Sample that got me the correct Win32 class.](http://www.activexperts.com/admin/scripts/wmi/vbscript/0615/)